# Is there a method or application which compares server configurations?

Tags: windows, configuration-management

I have windows staging and live servers for hosting our companies asp .net web applications.

Recently, there have been issues with changes existing between the staging environment and the live environment that have only been discovered during the release process.

Ideally, I would like to proactively monitor any differences between the servers to ensure that releases are as smooth as possible when moving the sites.

Also, we have a change management process in place for the servers but this provide a further degree of reassurance.

Thanks,

Brian.

Comment: *Also, we have a change management process in place for the servers but this provide a further degree of reassurance.* What does that statement mean, exactly? What's your process for moving things from staging to production? What exactly is being moved from staging to production; web sites, application pools, etc?

Comment: anytime you let a human touch a server things will be screwed up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know [SCOM](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/operations-manager.aspx) can do this for you, perhaps not to a byte level like diff'ing the drives but from a windows config perspective I'm pretty sure it'll do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the diff tool or the binary diff tool.

Comment: what diff tool, windiff?  There are many...

Answer (score 0):

[WebDeploy](http://leonardwoody.com/2010/11/29/web-deploy-or-msdeploy/) does a good job of capturing all configurations that are particular to ASP .Net Web Apps.  It captures app pools, registry settings, gac assemblies, etc.